# Error 500 Creating default object from empty value when uploading a file

Tags: php, yii, upload

I'm creating a form to upload a file, using yii and php 5.5.3. Here is my code in the controller:

```
foreach($_FILES['settings']['name'] as $settingName => $value) {
    $setting = Setting::model()->find('setting_name=:name', array(':name' => $settingName));
    $setting->image_file = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('settings['.$settingName.']');
    if (!empty($setting->image_file)) {
        $extension = "jpg";
        $filename = "";
        if (($pos = strrpos($setting->image_file, '.')) !== FALSE) {
            $extension = substr($setting->image_file, $pos + 1);
            $filename = substr($setting->image_file, 0, $pos)."_".strtotime("now");
        }
        if (!file_exists("uploads") and !is_dir("uploads"))
            mkdir("uploads", 0777, TRUE);

        $setting->image_file->saveAs("uploads/" . $filename.".".$extension, false);
        $setting->setting_value = "uploads/" . $filename.".".$extension;
        $setting->save();
    }
}
```

`image_file` is an extra attribute in model:

```
array('image_file', 'file', 'types' => 'gif, jpg, jpeg, png', 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024, 'tooLarge' => 'File upload must not exceed 1MB.'),
```

and here is the view:

```
<input type="file" name="settings[store_logo]" class="input-small">
```

`$setting->image_file->saveAs` can successfully upload the file, but it also generates

> Error 500 Creating default object from empty value

What went wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In which line do you have error 500? Can you update your question with all error stack?

Answer (score 0):

i guess, the $_FILES['settings']['name'] has a empty value in the last Key.
If you upload a File(s), they will be process as expected. The last value in your POST-array cause a NULL-return here:

```
// $setting === null
$setting = Setting::model()->find('setting_name=:name', array(':name' => $settingName))
```

and this call throws the 500.

```
$setting->image_file = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('settings['.$settingName.']');
```

This is my Version of your code:

```
<?php
foreach($_FILES['settings']['name'] as $settingName => $value) {
    $setting = Setting::model()->find('setting_name=:name', array(':name' => $settingName));

    // catch null-return 
    if(!$setting) {
        echo "can't find stuff at<pre>"; print_r($settingName); echo "</pre>";
        continue;
    }

    $setting->image_file = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('settings['.$settingName.']');

    if ($setting->image_file) {
        $extension = "jpg";
        $filename = "";
        if (($pos = strrpos($setting->image_file, '.')) !== FALSE) {
            $extension = substr($setting->image_file, $pos + 1);
            $filename = substr($setting->image_file, 0, $pos)."_".strtotime("now");
        }
        if (!file_exists("uploads") and !is_dir("uploads"))
            // dont 0777!       
            mkdir("uploads", 0740, TRUE);

            $setting->image_file->saveAs("uploads/" . $filename.".".$extension, false);
            $setting->setting_value = "uploads/" . $filename.".".$extension;
            $setting->save();
    }
}
?>
```